# filter file moves and copies from diff output

Tags: mercurial, diff

I look a lot at diff merges from mercurial, and it annoys me that moved files are shown as file deletion + file addition, often at two different places in the diff. It would be great if there was a way to replace that output by the message "file moved from .. to ..". The same goes for copied files.

I have heard that git has a copy detection algorithm that can also handle some changes in the files.

Is there a mercurial extension or a standalone tool I can feed my diff to that detects these file copies as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy detection mechanism in Mercurial has a ["similarity" parameter for `addremove` operation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#addremove):

```
[alias]
addremove = addremove --similarity 100
adrs = addremove --similarity 0.01
```

The [git(!) extended format](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#diff) might help you to get the desired output (as [illustrated here](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/05/what-i-hate-about-mercurial/)):

> Use the `-g`/`--git` option to generate diffs in the git extended [diff format](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#diffs).

```
$ mv c b

sjl at ecgtheow in ~/Desktop/test on default! 
$ hg addremove --similarity 100
adding b
removing c
recording removal of c as rename to b (100% similar)

sjl at ecgtheow in ~/Desktop/test on default! 
$ hg diff
diff --git a/c b/b
rename from c
rename to b
```

Comment: does the alias have an effect when using `hg commit -A`? I like to use qct as graphical frontend, so I have to check whether that works as well..

Comment: @daniel: it should. For instance, it does influence TortoiseHg (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295735/tortoisehg-copy-similarity-feature)